# Theoretical Question regarding Taylor Expansion

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I received the following question during a Calculus $2.0$ course in my university. I am not a native speaker, so please excuse my English.

The question is as follows:

> Let $f$ be a function with derivative of order $2$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with $f(0) \not = 0$ and there exists $M>0$ so that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $|f''(x)|\leq M$. Define $h=\sqrt{\frac{2|f(0)|}{3M}}$ and prove that if $f$ is not monotonic in $(-h,h)$, then there is no $x\in (-h,h)$ so that $f(x)=0$.

Our professor told us that all we need from the assumption of $f$ being non-monotonic in $(-h,h)$ is that there is a point $x\in (-h,h)$ so that $f' (x)=0$.

${\bf \text{What I did}}$:
After proving the existence of such a point, $x\in (-h,h)$ so that $f'(x)=0$, I used Taylor's Theorem on $f$, around that point to express $f$ as Taylor series of order $1$, plus remainder in the Lagrange form (Taylor Expansion). Then I managed to prove the required result but only for a radius of $\sqrt{2} h$ around that point. This means that I only need to take care of what happens when that point is close to the edges, $h$ or $-h$. This, in turn, means, that I need to prove that closer to the other edge, there is no $x\in (-h,h)$ so that $f(x)=0$. I was not able to do that.

That being said, I know that there cannot be two points, such that $f(x)=0$, because then, based on Rolle's theorem, there must be a point between these points where, again, $f'(x)=0$, and that contradicts what I found regarding what happens in radius of $\sqrt{2} h$, around such a point, since there was already a small continuous section of $(-h,h)$, where there could be $x\in (-h,h)$ so that $f(x)=0$.

I also thought about using a different point to build the Taylor Series around (say, around $x=0$. Then it's a Maclaurin series), and then carefully using something like the formula for the roots of a quadratic equation (the 'careful' part was due to the fact that the coefficient of the Remainder in the Lagrange form is a function), but it didn't amount to much.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Sorry for the English.

Comment: I fixed the formatting of the question. Please check that I did not mess up anything. See [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to write nice looking math formulas on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a, b\in (-h, h).$ Assume that $f'(a) = 0.$

Suppose that the function is equal to its Taylor series at $a.$ Then, up to second derivative

$$
\begin{align*}
f(x) - f(a) = \frac{1}{2}f''(a)(x - a)^2
\end{align*}
$$
If $x = 0,$ *!!!*
$$
\begin{align*}
f(0) - f(a) &= \frac{1}{2}f''(a)a^2\\
-f(a) &= -f(0) + \frac{1}{2}f''(a)a^2
\end{align*}
$$

If $f(b) = 0$ then
$$
\begin{align*}
-f(a) &= \frac{1}{2}f''(a)(b - a)^2\\
-f(0) + \frac{1}{2}f''(a)a^2 &= \frac{1}{2}f''(a)(b^2 - 2ab + a^2)\\
f(0) &= \frac{1}{2}f''(a)(2ab - b^2)\\
|f(0)| &= \frac{1}{2}|f''(a)||(2ab - b^2)| < \frac{1}{2}M3h^2\\
h &> \sqrt{\frac{2|f(0)|}{3M}}
\end{align*}
$$